# Convolution of the index function $h(x) = \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convolution

They ask me to calculate the convolution of the index function $h(x) = \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$.

Well $h * h(x) = \int_X h(y) \cdot h(x-y)dy = \int_X \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(y) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x-y)$.

I use that $0 < x-y < 1 \Rightarrow y < x \text{ and } y > x-1$ so $\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x-y) = \mathbb{1}_{(x-1,x)}(y)$.

Aplying this equality to my equation I have that:

$h * h(x) = \int_X \mathbb{1}_{(0,1) \cap (x-1,x)}(y)dy = \mu((0,1) \cap (x-1,x))$

I don't know if it is correct or not. And also I don't know how can I give an explicit solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. The explicit solution is the [triangular function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=piecewise%5B%7B%7B%5B%2F%2Ffunction%3Ax%2F%2F%5D%2C%5B%2F%2Frange%3A0%3C%3Dx%3C1%2F%2F%5D%7D%2C+%7B%5B%2F%2Ffunction%3A2-x%2F%2F%5D%2C%5B%2F%2Frange%3A1%3C%3Dx%3C2%2F%2F%5D%7D%7D%5D).

What remains to do is to break it into three cases:

$$
(0,1)\cap(x-1,x)=
\begin{cases}
(0,x) & \text{ if } 0\le x<1 \\
(x-1,1) & \text{ if } 1\le x<2 \\
\emptyset & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

so you get:

$$h*h(x)=
\begin{cases}
x & \text{ if } 0\le x<1 \\
2-x & \text{ if } 1\le x<2 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

Engineers call this [flip and slide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iIPvdmUegM).